# Are 'dividerHorizontal' and 'horizontalDivider' same? (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, divider

Are `horizontalDivider` and `dividerHorizontal` same?

Android Developers:

> [horizontalDivider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#horizontalDivider):
>
> Default horizontal divider between rows of menu items.

> [dividerHorizontal](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#dividerHorizontal):
>
> Drawable to use for generic horizontal dividers.

I'm going to use it in a `LinearLayout`:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:divider="?android:(dividerHorizontal or horizontalDivider)"
    ...>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which is better? Is there any difference in the design or how they're used? Or how they're referenced in (Java) code?

Comment: The same confusion with `dividerVertical` and `verticalDivider`.

Comment: You want to use `dividerHorizontal` there. `horizontalDivider` is specifically for menus, and may not be defined in a given theme. `dividerHorizontal` is for generic use – e.g., as a `View` separator, a text rule, etc. – and it should be defined in any complete theme. Same for the corresponding vertical ones.

Comment: I should've also mentioned that that's something you can modify in your theme, if you should need/want to; e.g., `<item name="android:dividerHorizontal">@drawable/your_much_cooler_divider</item>`. For reference, the default in a Material theme is [this platform drawable](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/drawable/list_divider_material.xml). If you do change that, be aware that the Jetpack libraries have their own `dividerHorizontal`, so be sure to set `name="android:dividerHorizontal"` in the theme, not `name="dividerHorizontal"`. Just FYI. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM., could you please convert it and post it as an answer?

Comment: Oh, jeez, sorry! Not sure how I missed your comment last week; I must've cleared my inbox without looking. Anyhoo, apologies again if this is a further inconvenience, but I'm not posting new answers here atm. Please feel free to finish up this question however you'd like. Thank you, though. I really appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Comment: Not a problem at all. Thanks for the answer. Will try to post an answer some time.